# IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'login.endpoint' in value "${login.endpoint}"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I am trying to launch a program using "Run as Spring Boot", I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'login.endpoint' in value "${login.endpoint}"

Here I'm having two projects, suppose A and B. In project B, my `application.properties` file is there and I'm reading those values as:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
```

I have added project B jar to project A. But whenever I'm executing project A, I'm getting the error above.

Could you please help me to resolve it?

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Config {

    @Value("${login.endpoint}")
    private String SERVICE_URL;
    
    @Value("${login.package}")
    private String PACKAGE;
    
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller adMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller(); 
        marshaller.setContextPath(PACKAGE);
        return marshaller;
    }
 
    @Bean(name="adAuthClient")
    public AppSoapClient adUnmarshaller(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        AppSoapClient adAuthClient = new AppSoapClient();
        adAuthClient.setDefaultUri(SERVICE_URL);
        adAuthClient.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        adAuthClient.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return adAuthClient;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer()
    {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: can you at least post the property file?

Comment: @Aman This is how my application.properties file looks like -
login.endpoint=http://188.0.0.22:8080/Redx/quick

Comment: For sure the property file is not being read, can you try running with `mvn spring-boot:run` if you are using `maven`. And it is a good practice to add default values for such properties.. like `${login.endpoint:defaultValue}`

Comment: @Aman tried mvn spring-boot:run but still no luck. Still getting the same error. Yes I tried the default option also but still getting the same error.

Comment: But, why the forward slash `classpath:/application.properties`. Should have been `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` I think

Comment: I've tried that also but still got the same error.

Comment: can you please show a gist of the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you access config file in another jar, you should define PropertySourceFactory in @PropertySource with prop factory. for example:

```java
@PropertySource(value = "application.properties",ignoreResourceNotFound = true, factory = MyPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

In that MyPropertySourceFactory, u can use PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver to search. It is more complicated.

```java
import org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader;
import org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MyPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    private static PropertySourceLoader loader = new PropertiesPropertySourceLoader();

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource)
            throws IOException {
        PropertySource<?> propSource = null;
        String propName = name;
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(propName)) {
            propName = getNameForResource(resource.getResource());
        }
        String fileName = resource.getResource().getFilename();
        List<Resource> resList = getPackageInsideResourcesByPattern("/**/" + fileName);

        for (Resource res : resList) {
             List<PropertySource<?>> propertySources = loader.load(propName, res);
            if (!propertySources.isEmpty()) {
                propSource = propertySources.get(0);
                break;
            }

        }
        return propSource;
    }


    private List<Resource> getPackageInsideResourcesByPattern(String resourceName) throws IOException {
        String resourcePathPattern = ResourcePatternResolver.CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX + resourceName;
        ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        return Arrays.asList(resourcePatternResolver.getResources(resourcePathPattern));
    }

    private String getNameForResource(Resource resource) {
        String name = resource.getDescription();
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(name)) {
            name = resource.getClass().getSimpleName() + "@" + System.identityHashCode(resource);
        }
        return name;
    }


}
```